# Angular Material Reactive Forms use the Validators in the HTML mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

Looking at the Angular Material demo, I cannot help but notice that the Validators in the TS file (required for instance) also require the required element to be added to the input element in the HTML.  I understand that this is from the [Angular Material Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-making-a-field-req):

> Caution: Use these HTML5 validation attributes in combination with the
>   built-in validators provided by Angular's reactive forms. Using these
>   in combination prevents errors when the expression is changed after
>   the template has been checked.

This is a similar question [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583529/angular-reactive-form-validation), except that I want to know if I can extract the validators in the HTML to add the fields automatically, and if so, how?

From the [Angular Material Form-Field Overview](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

In the HTML, the input line ends with the word `required`. What I want to be able to do is somehow extract this by checking the formgroup's email field, and if the `email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);` has the required validator, then add the word `required` to the `<input>` HTML tag, so I do not have to change it each time and risk them getting out of sync.

I could then do other things such as the minimum and maximum length, etc.

Comment: what I see from the question is that you're trying to put validation on both html and angular. Wouldn't it be redundant?

Comment: If use ReactiveForms, NOT put `required`, just use Validators.required

Comment: As per the question, the Angular team recommends the use, as per the highlighted section.  As it is redundant as I believe as well, I wanted to wrap the functionality which is why I am trying to do the changes I am asking about.  Also, the required element is needed for Angular Material to add the asterisk (*) to the field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ReactiveForms there is no need to put any validators in HTML. All the validation can be done in the ts file.

Here is an example of a login form with all the validations in ts file.

```
this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
  mobile: [
    null,
    Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(1000000000),
      Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")
    ])
  ],
  otp: [null, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(6),
        Validators.minLength(4)])],
});
```

In HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">

            <mat-form-field >
              <input  matInput type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" [formControl]="loginForm.controls['mobile']"
                >
              <mat-error
                *ngIf="loginForm.controls['mobile'].hasError('required') && ( loginForm.controls['mobile'].dirty === true || loginsubmitted === true )">
                Mobile number is <strong>required</strong>
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error
                *ngIf="loginForm.controls['mobile'].hasError('min') && ( loginForm.controls['mobile'].dirty === true || loginsubmitted === true )">
                Mobile number must contain <strong>10 digits</strong>
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error
                *ngIf="loginForm.controls['mobile'].hasError('pattern') && ( loginForm.controls['mobile'].dirty === true || loginsubmitted === true )">
                Invalid Mobile Number
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>



            <mat-form-field >
              <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Enter OTP"
                [formControl]="loginForm.controls['otp']">
              <mat-error
                *ngIf="loginForm.controls['otp'].hasError('required') && ( loginForm.controls['otp'].dirty === true || loginsubmitted === true )">
                OTP is <strong>required</strong>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>


            <button>LOGIN</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: I realize that the reactive form has the ability for validation in the code.  However, as per the Angular Material documentation, the Angular Material team does still recommend using the additional HTML elements.  As such, that is why I am trying to be able to get these added via code, so I can create a wrapper around the `<mat-form-field>` to allow me to only set the fields in the Typescript code.